# Handle specific HTTP answers correctly (OOP specific)

Tags: c#, oop, http

Currently I'm writing a bot for a browsergame and there are several responses.
They are unencrypted and the data is provided by a normal http response.

So because there are severaly slightly different response-types and structures I thought I could use my (low) oop knowledge to handle this - but my concept does not work.

I thought I can make for each request (login request, logout request, attack request, harvest request, ..) a own class which is a child from the basic request class.
And the same concept I thought I can do for the responses.

So here is a small demo of my code:

```
public class BasicRequest
{

     public BasicRequest(string serverId) { }

     public virtual BasicResponse DoRequest(string[] requestData)
     {
         // request is handled here
     }

}

public class LoginRequest : BasicRequest
{

     public LoginRequest(string serverId) : base(serverId) { }

}

public class BasicResponse
{

     public BasicResponse(string[] responseData) { }

     public virtual void DoSomeStuffWithTheResponse() { }
}

public class LoginResponse : BasicResponse
{

     public LoginResponse(string[] responseData) : base(responseData) { }

     public override void DoSomeStuffWithTheResponse() { }

}
```

This is my basic structure (ofc I have some more request and response classes).
Now I tried to use it like this:

```
LoginResponse response = new LoginRequest("serverXX").DoRequest(new string[] { "data" }) as LoginResponse;
```

But then 'response' is just null.
The important thing is, that it should perform the actions that the constructor of the base class do (this is some basic stuff that every request and response need) and then the constructor and the override of the specific class (loginrequest/response in this case) should be called.

Hope you can help me out, thanks in advice.

Comment: If I read it correctly, your problem is that the result of `DoRequest(new string[] { "data" }) as LoginResponse` is `null`. In that case`BasicResponse.DoRequest()` doesn't return a LoginResponse, but most likely a BasicResponse. You need to override DoRequest() in your LoginRequest class and return a LoginResponse.

Comment: And so if I understand the concept I call base.DoRequest(..) to let the BasicResponse class handle the prework, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't overriden `DoRequest` in your `LoginRequest` class, when you invoke `DoRequest` the base classes implementation is being called.

In order for this to work, `LoginRequest` needs to `override` the base implementation:

```
public class LoginResponse : BasicResponse
{
    public LoginResponse(string[] responseData) : base(responseData) { }

    public override void DoSomeStuffWithTheResponse()
    { 
    }

    public override BasicResponse DoRequest(string[] requestData) 
    {
        // Do stuff
        return new LoginResponse();
    }
}
```